# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. Laravel Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm using ajax to send comments. This is the route

```
Route::post('/users/add/comment/', 'UsersController@AddComment')->name('AddComment');
```

The ajax call

```
     function SendAny(){
        
          $.ajax({
                    url: '/users/add/comment/',
                    data: {
                        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                        "content": 'ksdflsdfnnkn',
                    },
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function(result) {

                        if (result == 0) {
                            location.reload();
                        } else {
                          
                            alert("this an ereor")
                        }
                    }
                });
        
    }
```

and the controller

```
  public function AddComment(Request $request){    
       dd($request);
}
```

It always throws that error. I changed the route and the func name a lot of times. but it does the same thing and the `dd();` request is always empty.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I channged it to 
`dataType: "json",`
                    `method: 'post',`

But it still the same ... sendind this route as GET.

Comment: You should use `type` if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @sta I'm using `jQuery v3.4.1`

Comment: In your `form` did you add `method="post"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to send the same data using `<form>` I tried AJAX to have more control over the request.

my form tag goes like `<form method="POST" action="/users/add/comment/">`
I removed the last `/` in the URL and it does work. I don't know how or why.

But It works !!!

Comment: It's work for me also

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `type` to `method`, you use the wrong keyword. Now it is a default GET

```
 $.ajax({
   url: '/users/add/comment/',
   data: {
     "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
     "content": 'ksdflsdfnnkn',
   },
   method: 'post', // it should be method: 'post'
   success: function(result) {

     if (result == 0) {
       location.reload();
     } else {

       alert("this an ereor")
     }
   }
 });
```

Comment: still the same

`Request Method: GET`
`Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed`

Comment: @MohamedA.Mahfouz i posted the answer to fast by accident, edited, but it takes some time for you to see the edited answer. replace type: 'post' by method: 'post'

Comment: @Gert B. No problem. I changed it but nothing happens,

Comment: @Cert B Yes still the same. check this https://i.ibb.co/61nBG1j/err.png

Comment: @MohamedA.Mahfouz I see 2 requests to /comment, one successful?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227323/discussion-between-gert-b-and-mohamed-a-mahfouz).

Comment: @Cert B I removed The `/` from the URL `comment/`and It does work. I can't figure why? :D

Comment: [`type` is an alias for `method`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), so should work, right?  My guess is missing `.preventDefault()`, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the ajax method to post with the attribute 'method', not 'type'.

function SendAny(){

```
      $.ajax({
                url: '/users/add/comment/',
                data: {
                    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                    "content": 'ksdflsdfnnkn',
                },
                method: 'post',
                success: function(result) {

                    if (result == 0) {
                        location.reload();
                    } else {
                      
                        alert("this an ereor")
                    }
                }
            });
    
}
```

Comment: Mwoah Seg Éh Gert! This is the same answer

Comment: woef! i'm sorry, don't know what happened here :-) oh, i know, you did not change the actual code :-)

Answer (score 0):

Form

```
<form id="YourForm">
 
 ...
    your inputs
 ...

</form>
```

Button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success SendButton">Save This</button>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.SendButton', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

            var data = $("#YourForm").serialize();

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
                });
            $.ajax({
                    method    : "POST",
                    url       : "{{ url('users/add/comment/') }}",
                    data      : data,
                    dataType  : "JSON",
                })
            .done(function(response) {
                
                alert('Success!');
                location.reload();
          
            .fail(function(response) {

                console.log("Error: ", response);

            });
        return false;

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort.